# Numbered list in Winter Bash blog post isn't working correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, list, winter-bash-2019

The list at the bottom of the [Winter Bash blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/09/tis-the-season-for-hats-join-us-for-winter-bash-2019/) has four steps, all numbered 1.:

> #### Whether you’re new to Winter Bash or need a quick refresher, here’s how it works:
>
> 1. Ask, answer, vote, edit, and chat to unlock fun hats and accessories you can wear on your avatar when you [complete challenges](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/) on participating sites.
>
> 1. Once you complete a challenge, a hat will appear on your profile.
>
> ...

Comment: These are parallel steps. We're supposed to async / await the whole thing.

Comment: Usually markdown on SE will [automatically number lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12145270/3357935). That feature must not be available on the blog.

Comment: Fixed already, 16:40GMT 9 Dec.